# Generating a variable that is the ratio of two values of another variable

Tags: sorting, stata

I have an individual level cross-sectional dataset. The observations are individuals belonging to a family which in turn is part of a household. The household can have one or multiple families.

My goal is to obtain the gender ratio of weekly housework hours by dividing the man's hours of housework with the partner's ones.

Variable `v31` is 1 when the individual is the principal member of the family (the woman) and 2 when the individual is the husband.

Variable `v4` is household ID.

Variable `v32` is the progressive number of the family within the household, 1 if the first family of the household, 2 if the second, and so on.

An example of the code:

```
clear

input obs v4 v32 v31 v850
1 1 1 1 27
2 1 1 2 12
3 2 1 2 8
4 2 1 1 41
5 3 1 2 0
6 4 1 1 29
7 4 1 2 11
8 4 2 1 37
9 4 2 2 1
end

list
```

By looking at the data example above, my goal would be to have a new variable called `domwork_ratio` which for example for line 1 and line 2 would have have the ratio of housework hours of the male partner and female partner, which would be 12/27. It will have the same value for both observations since they belong to the same family `v32` and  the same household `v4`.

I do not know how to tell Stata to do the ratio so that each husband's housework hours are divided by his partner's ones.

I have tried using the command:

```
bysort v4 v32 v16: gen domwork_ratio = cond(v4 != v4[_n-1],999999,v850_tot[_n-1]/v850_tot)
```

But for some reason the variable created has 999999 as the only value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the data example.

```
clear

input obs v4 v32 v31 v850
1 1 1 1 27
2 1 1 2 12
3 2 1 2 8
4 2 1 1 41
5 3 1 2 0
6 4 1 1 29
7 4 1 2 11
8 4 2 1 37
9 4 2 2 1
end

bysort  v32 v4 (v31) : gen ratio = v850[2] / v850[1] if v31[1] == 1 & v31[2] == 2 

list, sepby(v32 v4)

    +----------------------------------------+
     | obs   v4   v32   v31   v850      ratio |
     |----------------------------------------|
  1. |   1    1     1     1     27   .4444444 |
  2. |   2    1     1     2     12   .4444444 |
     |----------------------------------------|
  3. |   4    2     1     1     41   .1951219 |
  4. |   3    2     1     2      8   .1951219 |
     |----------------------------------------|
  5. |   5    3     1     2      0          . |
     |----------------------------------------|
  6. |   6    4     1     1     29   .3793103 |
  7. |   7    4     1     2     11   .3793103 |
     |----------------------------------------|
  8. |   8    4     2     1     37    .027027 |
  9. |   9    4     2     2      1    .027027 |
     +----------------------------------------+
```

The code that failed  refers to a variable `v16` which you didn't explain in the question. But its failure can be explained. The framework includes `by v4 v16:` and within groups so defined `v4` and `v16` are constant. Then such groups consist of single observations. For the first and only observation in each group it is true that `v4` is not equal to `v4[_n-1]` because `v4[0]` is returned as missing. Hence 999999 is, as reported, always returned. (As a matter of Stata programming style, returning system missing would be a better idea.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! v16 is a gender dummy so basically it does the same job as v31, my mistake was not putting v31 (or v16) between parenthesis. Anyways your answer works, thank you again.

Comment: Thanks for the full explanation. However, there is one part that I do not understand. If, as you said, it is not true that `v4[2]` differs from `v4[1]`, shouldn't the condition skip the 999999 part and return the `v850_tot[_n-1]/v850_tot)` ratio?

Comment: You're right. The problem lies elsewhere, I think,  that your `by:` prefix means that you are only looking at one observation in each group, as groups must have the same gender. Hence your mention of parentheses had the right flavour.

Answer (score 0):

As another potential solution, I was suggested to use the following code:

```
by v4 v32 (v31), sort: assert _N <= 2
by v4 v32 (v31): gen domworkratio = v850_tot[2]/v850_tot[1]
```

It should have the same outcome as the code suggested by Nick, I'm posting it here just to give another possibility.

Comment: The first command is irrelevant to the second unless it shows that the number of observations in each group is ever 3 or more If it is, then the second command may give incorrect results.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!